# Highcharts position polar area labels around outside

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I'm creating a polar area chart in Highcharts. I can't seem to get over the issue of the labels colliding into eachother when some chart segments are significantly smaller than others (if I turn off allowOverlap they just disappear). Is it possible to arrange the labels around the outside of the circle? I need to keep the chart responsive or else I'd absolutely position them.

```
chart: {
    polar: true,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0
}
```

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/u9w5hasw/

I've tried creating a new column series with every value set to 10 but this just squishes the data I already had. Tried a line series with labels as well but the labels position in the center of the point, not outside the circle, so they get obscured by the color fill.

Comment: Not a real solution, but you can use `dataLabels.x` and `dataLabels.y` per point, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/u9w5hasw/1/ - however you need to know that values in advance. Universal solution will be to wrap `alignDataLabel` method from the core. Or the last solution may be to translate labels in `chart.events.load` and `chart.events.redraw` method, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044479/highcharts-spline-datalabels-overlaping/20050449) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116858/aligning-datalabel-to-top-of-column-highcharts/15137818#15137818).

Comment: I don't think your example came through but that sounds like it would at least give me a responsive solution, correct? If I manually set an x and y coordinate for each label

Comment: x/y options are offsets for calculated positions from Highcharts, so kind of responsive solution. I can't promise there won't be a case with wrong positioned labels, though.

Comment: Ah offsets won't really work because the chart is dynamically generated from user responses and could have a variety of configurations. I guess I'll try making the labels HTML and absolutely positioning them.